# Issue Changing SearchView's Back Button Icon Color - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar, searchview

I am trying to change the color of the close button and the back button of my `SearchView`. I have got the color of the close button changing as expected, but I am having issues getting the back button's color to change. I want them both to be black, but the back button is stuck as white right now.

[image]

I have looked through a bunch of solutions to similar answers, but most are making style changes to the app's `Toolbar`. I have created a custom `menu` resource and do not have a `Toolbar` to change the style of.

I have also tried changing the `Drawable` icon of the support action bar using the `setHomeAsUpIndicator` function, but this had no effect.

This is the small amount of code I am using to change the close and back button colors.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.navbar_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    
    ImageView closeImgView = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    closeImgView .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
    
    ImageView backImgView = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    backImgView .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is this back button not the same as the `R.id.search_mag_icon`? If not, then where is this back button coming from and how can I change its style?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for setting your imageview colour in xml like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_mag_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="your image file"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"  /*for changing your image colour*/ 
 />
```

or try use setBackgroundColour for alternate

```
search_mag_icon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000"));
```

Comment: The issue with the firsts solution is that `search_mag_icon` is the id of an `ImageView` that is built into `SearchView`. The only way I can access it is using the `findViewById` as shown in the question. The second solution also doesn't seem to be changing the icon.